# lock issue on tables due to triggers

Tags: mysql, triggers, database-deadlocks, table-lock

I am new to Triggers and am facing some lock issue on TransactionDateTracking table (duplicate entry message on inserting in TransactionDateTracking) ) when I used triggers. The following are the table structures

CREATE TABLE `TransactionDateTracking` (
  `Id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `TransactionTrackType` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `TransactionTrackDate` date NOT NULL,
  `LastRunDate` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`Id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `TransactionTrackType_UNIQUE` (`TransactionTrackType`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=645 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

CREATE TABLE `JournalJobLog` (
  `TransformationId` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `TransformationName` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `LastUpdated` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `LastFailureDate` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `RevisionNumber` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`TransformationName`),
  KEY `IDX_JournalJobLog` (`TransformationId`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=302 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

The below are two triggers which I used -
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS JournalJobLogInsert;

DELIMITER $$

CREATE TRIGGER JournalJobLogInsert AFTER INSERT ON `TransactionDateTracking` FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN 
 INSERT INTO JournalJobLog
  SET TransformationName=NEW.TransactionTrackType,
     LastUpdated=NEW.TransactionTrackDate;
END$$

DELIMITER ;

===============================================================

DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS JournalJobLogUpdate;

DELIMITER $$

CREATE TRIGGER JournalJobLogUpdate AFTER UPDATE ON `TransactionDateTracking` FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN

```
INSERT INTO JournalJobLog (TransformationName, LastUpdated) VALUES(NEW.TransactionTrackType, NEW.TransactionTrackDate) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE    
LastUpdated=NEW.TransactionTrackDate;
```

END$$

DELIMITER ;

The problem is am unable to insert any entry in TransactionDateTracking stating "Duplicate entry" message sometime. When I drop the triggers it works fine.

Comment: Well, this sounds like you do have a row with that `TransactionTrackType` in `JournalJobLog` already. So on your next duplicate entry, check for that. You'll then have to figure out wether it should be there or not (and adept your trigger for that) or why it is there if shouldn't.

Comment: TransactionTrackType (For TransactionDateTracking) and TransformationName (for JournalJobLog) hold the same values and even if I don't have the row on update I am doing insert/update.

Comment: Yes, I am aware of that. If you insert e.g. `TransactionTrackType = 1` into `TransactionDateTracking` and the error occurs, MySQL coplains that there is, *before you insert*, a row with `TransformationName = 1` in `JournalJobLog` (as the trigger inserts another row with `TransformationName = 1` and fails). So when this error occurs, do a `select * from JournalJobLog where TransformationName = 1` (with your actual value) to verify that. And then decide/tell us if it's ok if that row already exists (we don't know that) and either fix the trigger or find the reason why that row exists and fix it.